# What's the dotnet replacement for `nuget install`?

Tags: .net, nuget

I've been trying to adapt our CI/CD system at work to use the installed .NET SDK (via `dotnet`) instead of a nuget executable. I've managed to do this now for most calls to nuget, but this one is evading me.

`nuget install` allows us to specify a config file using `nuget install -ConfigFile <file>`, which we use heavily.

I believe the analogue of `nuget install` is `dotnet add package`. However, there are two issues with this:

1. This requires a .csproj file for some reason. I've tried creating an empty project using `dotnet new classlib`, but until the point below is solved, I don't think I'll be sure that this is doing the right thing.
2. There doesn't seem to be a way to specify the config file. Does it look in a specific place for a config file? Can I specify one? Or should I put my config file in a specific place? I've got the NuGet.Config file in the root directory for my project, but it looks to me like it's not using it.

Any advice to help me solve this issue would be really appreciated.

Comment: dotnet add package, however you need a project that supports packages as console project or we project

Comment: dotnet add package - Adds or updates a package reference in a project file. You must specify which project you want to add to this NuGet package. If your .csproj already has references to NuGet packages, when you run a dotnet build it will implicitly restore the packages

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/12513